# Finding an efficient algorithm to answer queries in a submatrix of a given square matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I'm trying to solving the [“Rectangular Queries” problem from the December 2013 CodeChef contest](http://www.codechef.com/DEC13/problems/RECTQUER):

Given a square matrix N x N, filled with integers from {1,..10}. We are given Q(10^5) queries as follows
given x1,y1, x2,y2 find the number of unique elements in the given sub matrix.

Limits:
N <= 300
Q (10^5)
x1 <= x2 <= N
y1 <= y2 <= N
time limit 1 sec.

I have tried an approach using std::set for uniqueness but getting TLE...MY approach is naive...looping from top left to bottom right for a query and adding elements to set..then printing std::set.size().

Comment: Actually the number of queries are 10^5...the submatrix will be changing for very query...i need to answer the query either in O(log(N)) or O(1)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possible approaches :-

1. Solve the problem on your own and get hard earned points.
2. Wait for contest to end and view solutions in editorials.

Good luck.

Comment: You are right...Actually i was so frustrated with this problem..it is not clicking...Thanx.Let me struggle..:)

Comment: @AdityaBahuguna Thats the spirit , best of luck and sorry if i hurt your feelings in any way but it is unfair to other participants if get solutions from SO. Best of luck

Comment: Now you can tell me...what is the other way.

Comment: My approach was this..i made a matrix where each cell is a 10 field integer array..ie mat[n][n][10]. mat[x][y][i] denotes the number of occurences of i from 0,0 to x,y. we build this...now for each query i have to iterate 10 times and to check whether a number is present or not i have this formula mat[x2][y2][i] - mat[x1-1][y2][i] - mat[x2][y1-1][i] + mat[x1-1][y1-1][i].this is positive means there is some frequency of i in x1,y1 to x2,y2 submatrix..

Comment: @AdityaBahuguna Good approach and more efficient but i prevented doing that to a simpler solution. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution that would do it in time limit : -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define max 300
int count[max][10][max];
int matrix[max][max];
int N;

void gen_counts() {
 int i,j,k,number,index;

 for(i=0;i<N;i++) {

    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
       count[i][j][0] = 0;
 }

 for(i=0;i<N;i++) {

   for(j=0;j<10;j++) {

    for(k=0;k<N;k++) {
        if(k>0)
           count[i][j][k] = count[i][j][k-1];

        if(matrix[i][k]==j+1) {
             count[i][j][k]++;
        }  

     }

   }

 }


}

int get_distinct(int r1,int c1,int r2,int c2) {
   int i,j,present[10],ret=0;
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
      present[i] = 0; 
   for(i=r1;i<=r2;i++) {

     for(j=0;j<10;j++) {
        if(c1>0) 
        present[j]=present[j]||(count[i][j][c1-1]<count[i][j][c2]);
        else present[j] = present[j] || (count[i][j][c1]>0||count[i][j][c2]>0);
     }

   }
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
     ret = ret + present[i];

  return(ret);
}



int main() {

int Q,i,j,r1,r2,c1,c2;

scanf("%d",&N);

for(i=0;i<N;i++) {

 for(j=0;j<N;j++)
   scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
}

gen_counts();

scanf("%d",&Q);

for(i=0;i<Q;i++) {

 scanf("%d%d%d%d",&r1,&c1,&r2,&c2);
 printf("%d\n",get_distinct(r1-1,c1-1,r2-1,c2-1));

}


return(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the optimal algorithm for this problem ... i think its complexity is also less than O(n*n) . i think it will be useful

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int n,i,j;
//read matrix dimensions
scanf("%d",&n);

int mat[n][n];
int t,x1,x2,y1,y2;
int counter[10],flag;
//read matrix
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        scanf("%d",&mat[i][j]);
    }
}

scanf("%d",&t);
//for each test case do this
while(t--){
    scanf("%d%d%d%d",&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2);

    //make all counters zero
    for(i = 0;i<10;i++){
        counter[i]=0;
    }

    flag = 0;

    for(i=x1-1;i<=x2-1;i++){
        for(j=y1-1;j<=y2-1;j++){
            //counter == 0 means we are visiting the element for the first time 
            counter[mat[i][j]-1]++;
        }

    }



    for(i =0;i<10 ;i++){
        if(counter[i]!=0){
            flag++;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n",flag);

}
return 0;
}
```